# replacing a string with space

Tags: bash

This is the code

```
for f in tmp_20100923*.xml  
do  
 str1=`more "$f"|grep count=`  
 i=`echo $str1 | awk -F "." '{print($2)}'`  
 j=`echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}'` // output is `count="0"`  
 sed 's/count=//g' $j > $k; echo $k;   
done
```

I tried to get value 0 from above output using sed filter but no success. Could you please advise how can i separate 0 from string `count="0"` ?

Comment: Hi, the xml file has line 
`<expr1:expr2.expr3 count="0" expr4="yyyy-mm-ddT23:55:00.041Z" expr5="0.0" expr6="0.0"/>`. 

So, our output should be sum of integer values from count for different files in FOR loop i.e 0+2+...

So, what i did 

for f in tmp_20100923*.xml  
do  
 str1=`more "$f"|grep count=`  // grep the line which has pattern `count=`
 i=`echo $str1 | awk -F "." '{print($2)}'`  // output is `expr3 count="0" expr4="yyyy-mm-ddT23:55:00`
 j=`echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}'` // output is `count="0"`  
 sed 's/count=//g' $j > $k; echo $k;   // now the aim is to get 0 from above
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have AWK do everything:

```
for f in tmp_20100923*.xml  
do  
    k=$(awk -F '.' '/count=/ {split($2,a," "); print gensub("count=","","",a[2])}')
done
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, you don't need to split on the decimal. You can also have AWK do the summation. So you don't need a shell loop.

```
awk '/count=/ { sub("count=","",$2); gsub("\042","",$2); sum += $2} END{print sum}' tmp_20100923*.xml
```

Comment: yah, any time you have a long sequence of grep, sed and awk, it's almost always better to just replace it with a short awk program.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all non digits from `$j`:

```
echo ${j//[^0-9]/}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to sed a file whose name is $j

Instead you can

```
echo $j | sed 's/count=//g'
```

Comment: this is also true, as the third argument to sed is the file. from the man page `sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...`

Answer (score 0):

This should snag everything between the quotes.

`sed -re 's/count="([^"]+)"/\1/g'`

`-r` adds `--regexp-extended` to be able to cool stuff with regular expressions, and the expression I've given you means:

```
search for count=",
then store ( any character that's not a " ), then
make sure it's followed by a ", then
replace everything with the stuff in the parenthesis (\1 is the first register)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed regexp:

```
sed 's/count="\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

However your script has another problem:

```
j=`echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}'` // output is `count="0"`  
sed 's/count=//g' $j > $k; echo $k;
```

should be

```
j=`echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}'` // output is `count="0"`  
echo $j | sed 's/count=//g'
```

or better:

```
echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}' | sed 's/count=//g'
```

'sed' accepts filenames as input. $j is a shell variable where you put the output of another program (awk).

Also, the ">" redirection puts things in a file. You wrote ">$k" and then "echo $k", as if >$k wrote the output of sed in the $k variable.

If you want to keep the output of sed in a $k variable write instead:

```
j=`echo $i | awk -F " " '{print($2)}'` // output is `count="0"`  
k=`echo $j | sed 's/count=//g'`
```